# Gradle cannot find JUnit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit, junit5

In Java, I have the following tests:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

abstract class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    static void testTwoPlusTwoIsFour() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }

    @Test
    static void testMinusOneThatsThree() {
        assertEquals(3, -1);
    }
}
```

Running `gradle build` gives me the following output:

```
Test run finished after 95 ms
        [         1 containers found      ]
        [         0 containers skipped    ]
        [         1 containers started    ]
        [         0 containers aborted    ]
        [         1 containers successful ]
        [         0 containers failed     ]
        [         0 tests found           ]
        [         0 tests skipped         ]
        [         0 tests started         ]
        [         0 tests aborted         ]
        [         0 tests successful      ]
        [         0 tests failed          ]
```

It seems Gradle cannot find any tests in any test classes that I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out,

### Gradle cannot find tests which are `static`, `private` or in an `abstract` class.

The following *method* access modifiers are valid for a **test method**:

- package-private (no modifier)
- `protected`
- `public`

The following *class* access modifiers are valid for a **test class**:

- package-private (no modifier)
- `public`

**The following keywords are *not* valid for tests:**

- `abstract`
- `static`
- `private`

---

Just removing the `abstract` and `static` keywords from the tests would fix everything:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    void testTwoPlusTwoIsFour() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }

    @Test
    void testMinusOneThatsThree() {
        assertEquals(3, -1);
    }
}
```

Gradle output:

```
Test run finished after 158 ms
        [         2 containers found      ]
        [         0 containers skipped    ]
        [         2 containers started    ]
        [         0 containers aborted    ]
        [         2 containers successful ]
        [         0 containers failed     ]
        [         2 tests found           ]
        [         0 tests skipped         ]
        [         2 tests started         ]
        [         0 tests aborted         ]
        [         1 tests successful      ]
        [         1 tests failed          ]
```

Comment: love the maths reference